# RSpecでFakerを使って設定したメールアドレスが実在するかどうか

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

RSpecでFakerを使って設定したメールアドレスは実在するのでしょうか？

今はまだないのですが、ユーザーにメールを飛ばすような機能を作り始めた時に、
Fakerを使って設定したメールアドレスに意図せずにメールが飛んだら問題になると思ってます。

たとえば、ドメインがありえないものを設定している、、とかであればそこまで心配することはないと思っています。ご存じの方いれば教えてください。
ちなみにこれまでの仕事では、example.comのドメイン宛にとばせばそのメールアドレスは存在しないから、
それを設定しよう、、みたいに教わってきました。

Answer (score 1):

生成方法によって実在するemailにも
`example.org`や`example.net`にもなるようです。

https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/internet.md

> ## Optional argument name=nil
>
> Faker::Internet.free_email #=> "freddy@gmail.com"
>
> Faker::Internet.free_email('Nancy') #=> "nancy@yahoo.com"
>
> ## Optional argument name=nil
>
> Faker::Internet.safe_email #=> "christelle@example.org"
>
> Faker::Internet.safe_email('Nancy') #=> "nancy@example.net"